# Check for malware in firmware

Tags: security

What is the most efficient way to check for malware residing in firmware through open source software? I wondered to what extent standard commercial antivirus software detects this type of malware.

Comment: Is there an actual problem that you're trying to solve? What OS and version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4. It is a general security concern.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to do a byte by byte comparison of the firmware. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126132/how-to-dump-bios-data-to-a-file has a couple of methods to view and dump firmware. But you will need an older dump to be able to compare.

> I wondered to what extent standard commercial antivirus software detects this type of malware.

It does not and does not even scan for it.